# Regular expression, parsing img src content and replacing it with another links

Tags: php, html, regex, image

I need to make next feature on my site: user writing an article and attach image in it, images are often stored not on localhost. I need to download this images to localhost and replace links to localhost images.

For example:

```
<img ... src="http://bob.com/img/image1.png" ... >
<img ... src="http://bob.com/img/image2.png" .... >
```

Script will find `src` content, download images and replace it like this:

```
<img ... src="/images/image1.png" ... >
<img ... src="/images/image2.png" .... >
```

I understand how to parse all `src` from code:

```
$subject = # i will put there article content (with img tags etc)
$result = array();
preg_match("/<img.*?src="(.*?)".*?>/", $subject, $result);
```

Now `$result` array will contain all link to images. Nice. Now I have some questions.

**1)** If I use `preg_replace`, will it help me to solve this task? In my opinion not, because `preg_replace` will replace content instantly (so I can't download image, create new link for stored on localhost image and somehow set this as argument for `preg_replace`, because it is run yet). Am I right with this assumption?

**2)** Okay. I can form an array, like I said. After that I download all images from this array. After that, somehow, I will replace all old images, for new images. I think it is more realistic. Am I right?

Something like that:

```
$subject = # i will put there article content (with img tags etc)
$result = array();
preg_match("/<img.*?src="(.*?)".*?>/", $subject, $result);

foreach($result as $src)
{
 $new_src = downloadImage($src);
 # somehow replace old image with new image there. How?
}
```

**3)** How exactly I can replace links if I will use 2nd method?

Comment: Have you tried [Php::DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) ? It's much easier to manipulate DOM than Regex and is OOP ;)

Comment: Uhm. Can you give an example then?

Comment: saw "regular expression" followed by "parsing" in the title. cringed.

Comment: Try DOM, [not regexes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/471272).

Answer (score 1):

A Php DOMDocument Example how to manipulate HTML image tags.

```
$dom=new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html_src);
$imgs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach($imgs as $img){
    
    $img_src = $img->getAttribute('src'); // will give you the src String
    
    //do something here

    $img->setAttribute('src',$new_src); // change your src= value

}
```

You can manipulate everything with `setAttribute` when the Attribute exist.

If you want be sure, that `src` is set, then you can use [`hasAttribute`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.hasattribute.php)

Comment: 1 second. `$html_src` - what is content of this variable? And will `Php::DomDocument` will work with variables? I mean... User wrote an article, I will save it in some variable. Can I work with this variable by `Php::DomDocument`? Well, 2nd question is not too important, if I will know answer for first one.

Comment: in my example $html_src is the html content from the page to show you how to load the html source

Comment: Ok. But I need to swap links in a text, which was inputted by user. Is it possible? Like so: `$text = $_POST['article_text']; $dom=new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($text); .... #etc`

Comment: Yes, you could use it like this, when your $_POST variable contains html code, but maybe you have to overthink it, when you have to send HTML code through $_POST.

Comment: I am adding news/article to my site. I fill in all fields in form (title, message, tags etc...), pressing send button and handler, which will get `$_POST` parameters loading. Whats wrong? How I can do it another ways?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [preg_replace_callback](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) but keep in mind that `downloadImage` may fail. so handle the failure gracefully (a fallback image or a retry queue)