# How to retrive the alt value from an image tag which is found in an <a> tag

Tags: php, dom

Suppose i have

```
<html>    
<body>   
<a href="www.example.com" ><img src="www.example.com/gc_bt1.jpg" alt="Home page..." name="Image1" width="150" height="27" border="0" id="Image1" /></a>    </body>    </html>
```

how can i retrieve the alt value from the image tag.

Comment: Why are you trying parse this with PHP? That's a lot more complex than with javascript, because you actually need to parse the markup which brings in XML parsing/object reading.

Comment: This was my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21390578/regular-expression-parsing-img-src-content-and-replacing-it-with-another-links/21399443#21399443) , it was for a <img> but you could change it to a <a>-Tag

Comment: i think the solution about changing the <img> to <a> can actually work..I won't do that now because i am writing my own script :)
i will try your given solution tomorrow :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript for that

```
var x = document.getElementsByName("Image1").alt;
```

Comment: I want to use php to do that

Comment: However, watch for `getElementsByName` returning an array, `.alt` would not apply to the array but to the elements within.

Answer (score -1):

if you are using Jquery

`var alt=$("a>img").attr('alt')`

will give you the alt tag